# Angular submit data on one page and read it on another

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a **reportForm** page where the user fills out stuff and post it to generate a report.

```
reportData = {
 headline: $scope.headline,
 fromDate: $scope.fldFromDate,
 toDate: $scope.fldToDate,
 whatever: $scope.whatever 
}

$http.post(reportUrl + $scope.reportName, reportData)
 .then(function successCallback(data) {
    console.log("Ok");
 }, function errorCallback(err) {
    console.log("Call Report ERROR: " + err);
 });
}
```

Then I have a lot of different **generate report** pages that take the data the user filled out and uses this to generate a report he can print (this is my reason to make the reports separate pages).

QUESTION:   How can the **generate report** page read the data submitted by the **reportForm** page?

I tried to read about factory and service and rootscope, but I can't really see how they would work?  Am I submitting data to another page right?  So how can they share data between them using these angular functions?  (I'm very new to angular, so be gentle please hehe:-)))

in nodejs, I would use a router to read the get/post data.

Comment: Perhaps I need to think of Angular as one big page, instead of many different pages?

Comment: if I use factory or rootscope, then how can I make that work?  Would I have to compile all the pages together or how is that done with angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure of what you're trying to do. But if ...

1/ you want to pass data from an angular location to another, you can use service as Sajeetharan shows here : 
[Unable to bind $scope value to view on Url change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43952459/unable-to-bind-scope-value-to-view-on-url-change)

2/ you're trying to post data to a server, then retrieve data from that server.
Then you would post it as you did, and retrieve it in another page using `$http.get`

Comment: Hi, let me try and explain.  I have a html page-one with a controller and a form, and a html page-two with a controller and a table. I want to share/send the data in page-one to page-two.

Comment: Then you should go with method 1/ and use a service