# Unable to bind $scope value to view on Url change

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I trying to create a search application using angularJS.I am facing the issue in binding $scope values to view when router Url changes.

I have a search field in /main.When I write the query and click on search button, the function does the data fetch and assign to a scope variable.The router URL will change to '/Result' and the respective view is displayed.But the view doesn't have the scope values bound. /main and /Result uses the same controller.

router code in main module :

```
 $routeProvider.
                      when('/main', {
                          templateUrl: '/views/search.html',
                          controller: 'searchCtrl'


                            }).when('/Result',{                                 
                                templateUrl:'/views/Result.html',
                                  controller: 'searchCtrl' ,
                                  reloadOnSearch: false


                                }).otherwise({      

                          redirectTo: '/main'
                      });
```

**Controller :
On button click from /main**

```
$scope.fetchResult=function(searchWord){

 shService.fetchResultDocumentsList(searchWord).data.then(function(response){
//service call here-data fetch is successfull.
 $scope.docResultList=response[0];
                 $scope.docResultList=response[0];
                 $scope.documents =  $scope.docResultList.data.documentEntities;
$location.path('/Result');
}
```

When the respective view is changing, the binding is not done.**But when i replace the $scope.documents with $rootScope.documents binding is successful.**
I have read the use of $scope is encouraged over $rootScope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller and **`$scope`** gets re initialized when you move from one page to another page. if you want to use $scope , you should consider using **`service`** to share the data across controllers.

Create a service, that will hold your variable.

```
angular.service("dataService", function() {
    this.value1 = ""   
});
```

reference that service in your controllers,

```
angular.controller("myCntrl1", function($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.val= dataService.value1 ;
});


angular.controller("myCntrl2", function($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.val= dataService.value1 ;
});
```

Comment: /main and the /Result uses the same controller as there is a common function used by the same(the function i mentioned above).

Comment: @stars even if you use same controlleer , it will gets re initialized when your route changes

Answer (score 0):

As Sajeetharan said, $scope get reinitialized when you update location.

Using angularJs, you don't need to change location. You simply update $scope in the same view you used for searching.
But if you really need to use another view, and assuming your search returns only strings, you could try to pass data through url, and grab it from your controller.

Something like this (not tested):

### Solution 1 (Angular way)

**Controller**

```
$scope.documents = ""; // init your results to empty/null, as you need

$scope.fetchResult=function(searchWord){

 shService.fetchResultDocumentsList(searchWord).data.then(function(response){
//service call here-data fetch is successfull.
 $scope.docResultList=response[0];
                 $scope.docResultList=response[0];
                 $scope.documents =  $scope.docResultList.data.documentEntities;
$location.path('/Result');
}
```

**View**

```
<!-- search div is over here -->

<!-- results goes here -->
<div ng-if="$scope.documents">
 {{$scope.documents}}
</div>
```

### Solution 2 (your way)

**Router**

```
$routeProvider.

when('/main', {
templateUrl: '/views/search.html',
controller: 'searchCtrl'})

.when('/Result/{data:[a-z]{1,}}',{ //here we specify that data expected format is only lowercase letters
 templateUrl:'/views/Result.html',
 controller: 'searchCtrl' ,
 reloadOnSearch: false
})
.otherwise({      
 redirectTo: '/main'
});
```

**Controller**

```
//  dont forget to inject $stateParams service in your controller
if( !$stateParams.data){
 $scope.data = $stateParams.data;
}
```

Comment: I need to use a different view as the the view used in /main is only for search input and the result is displayed in respective view associated with /Result